# Shell32 File extractor script for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, zip, shell32

I am writing a vb.net script for distribution but I have run into a problem. The script can't extract zip files using the COM referenced Shell32 library without triggering antivirus since I am building into an exe. I was wondering if anyone knew a better way to extract the files in vb.net or simply a way that antivirus would not delete my script since this is going to be a distributed program.

Disabling antivirus is not a solution so don't suggest it.

Comment: I use the free Ionic Zip library: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Private Sub unzip()
    Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
    'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
    Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("D:\unzip")
    'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
    Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("D:\zipFiles\")
    'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
    output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)
 End Sub
```

Comment: I have already tried this and using shell32 anything will trigger my anti-virus. I don't want my users to have the same problem.

Comment: @BrandonBatton i too using the same till now no anti-virus made any problem btw where your `shell32.dll` located in my case `C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll`

Comment: Ok so I spent the night breaking up my program to figure out what was causing it. I think it is actual the bit of code right before my unzip call which downloads a file from a url.